# pods in kubernetes can not communicate with other pods and outside cluster hosts

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I have 2 master and 3 worker node and one HA proxy for controlePlan,
I have many java microservices that communicate together and communicate with DB or KAFKA outside of the kubernetes cluster.
network access is any to any open in all hosts.
I create deployment for every microservices.
But when I exec to container I don't have tcp connection on ports between pods and DB or KAFKA outside of the kubernetes cluster.

from hosts I have telnet to DB or KAFKA But in container pods I don't access.

from hosts:

```
[root@master1 ~]# telnet oracle.local 1521
Trying 192.198.10.30...
Connected to oracle.local.
Escape character is '^]'.
^C^CConnection closed by foreign host.
[root@master1 ~]#
```

from pod for example busybux :

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # telnet 192.168.10.30 1521
telnet: can't connect to remote host (192.168.10.30): Connection timed out
```

cluster status:

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                 STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                  KERNEL-VERSION                  CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master1.project.co   Ready    control-plane,master   11d   v1.22.2   192.168.10.1    <none>        Oracle Linux Server 8.3   5.4.17-2011.7.4.el8uek.x86_64   containerd://1.4.9
master2.project.co   Ready    control-plane,master   11d   v1.22.2   192.168.10.2    <none>        Oracle Linux Server 8.3   5.4.17-2011.7.4.el8uek.x86_64   containerd://1.4.9
worker1.project.co   Ready    <none>                 11d   v1.22.2   192.168.10.3   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 8.3   5.4.17-2011.7.4.el8uek.x86_64   containerd://1.4.9
worker2.project.co   Ready    <none>                 11d   v1.22.2   192.168.10.4   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 8.3   5.4.17-2011.7.4.el8uek.x86_64   containerd://1.4.9
worker3.project.co   Ready    <none>                 11d   v1.22.2   192.168.10.5   <none>        Oracle Linux Server 8.3   5.4.17-2011.7.4.el8uek.x86_64   containerd://1.4.9
```

describe pod busybox:

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubectl describe pod busybox
Name:         busybox
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         worker3.project.co/192.168.10.5
Start Time:   Sat, 02 Oct 2021 10:27:05 +0330
Labels:       run=busybox
Annotations:  cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 75d7222e8f402c68d9161a7b399df2de6b45e7194b2bb3b0b2730adbdac680c4
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.205.76/32
              cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.205.76/32
Status:       Pending
IP:
IPs:          <none>
Containers:
  busybox:
    Container ID:
    Image:         busybox
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Args:
      sh
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ContainerCreating
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-69snv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-69snv:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  21s   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/busybox to worker3.project.co
  Normal  Pulling    20s   kubelet            Pulling image "busybox"
```

Answer (score 2):

A number of reasons may be the cause of that.
Without proper insight to your cluster and network architecture this won't be solved, however, here are some ideas:

1. Check if there are any [NetworkPolicies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) applied by executing `kubectl -n <namespace> get netpol`. NetworkPolicies can restrict the communication within and to the outside of the cluster.
2. Let a Pod run with the [`hostNetwork: true` option](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/123997.htm) (**not** to be done in production, just as a test) and try some connectivity tests again (in both directions).
3. Check if your cluster's network is properly configured by tracing a network call. Are the routers properly configured and can be used by applications within the cluster?
4. Check if your `network access is any to any open in all hosts` statement is true, it may be an issue with firewall configurations.

Bonus:
You seem to only have 2 master nodes which does **not make any sense at all** if etcd is running within the Kubernetes cluster (`kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep etcd` will show 2 pods if that is the case). [Having 2 etcd members give you the exact same failure tolerance as a 1 node cluster but you wasted resources on having another VM that takes up memory, cpu, etc](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3/faq/#what-is-failure-tolerance). Consider increasing your master nodes to 3 in order to have a failure tolerance of one. There always must be *a majority* of the etcd cluster running. Keep in mind that the majority of 2 is still 2.

Comment: 1-[root@master1 ~]# kubectl get netpol --all-namespaces
No resources found  2-when I using hostNetwork: true the issue resolved, But telnet to worker is successful , Telnet to out of cluster is successful , how to telnet with hostname because schedule is auto I don't know container deployed on which host 4- selinux and firewalld are disable

Comment: It appears as it is number 3 then. Your cluster networking does not seem to make use of your gateways.
You can use number 2 as a **temporary** workaround. You can use the `nodeName` or `nodeSelector` feature to decide which node the pod shall run on: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodename

With that you can then connect to the pod by using the hostname of the node it is running on.

Comment: with hostnetwork and nodeSelector issue solved, but I don't know why without hostnetwork I cant see out of cluster . the host don't has problem but the pods can not connect with other hosts